# Change product price depending on js script output

Tags: javascript, php, opencart, shopping-cart

I have OpenCart 1.5.6. Inside the product page, a javascript `count.js` is attached to the text area

```
counter = function() {
    var value = $('#bob').val();
    if (value.length == 0) {
        $('#wordCount').html(o);
        return;
    }
var wordCount = value.split(/\s+/)
                     .filter(function(v){ return v.length>2 })
                     .length;
    $('#wordCount').html(wordCount);
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#count').click(counter);
    $('#bob').change(counter);
    $('#bob').keydown(counter);
    $('#bob').keypress(counter);
    $('#bob').keyup(counter);
    $('#bob').blur(counter);
    $('#bob').focus(counter);
});
```

I want the price to dynamically change depending on the output. So for example I want the price to become

```
price = price * wordcount;
```

So that the price changes depending on the amount of words that are entered into the textbox

Can someone please help me to do that. My php knowledge is minimal, and I'm not sure where, in what file, can i make that happen, and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to learn a bit of PHP for this.

First of all your text area (bob, I presume) should be set up as an option for the product with a type of "Textarea". Then set the product's price to be whatever the price per word is.

In catalog/controller/product/product.php, you need to add the following code:

```
$this->data['word_price'] = $this->tax->calculate($product_info['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'));
```

In your product.tpl make sure where the price is displayed is encapsulated by `<span id="product_price">xxx</span>`

Then in your javascript function `counter()` at the beginning

```
var word_price = <?php echo (float)$word_price; ?>;
```

(Though you'll need to first take your function out of count.js and put it in the product.tpl inside `<script>` tags)

And at the end of the function counter()

```
$('#product_price').val(word_price * wordCount);
```

That will get it displaying on the product detail page.

You'll also need to make changes in /system/engine/cart.php to calculate the price again when it gets added to the cart. (You don't want the browser to be telling your system what the price is!)

In function `getProducts()` in the following `if` statement..

```
elseif ($option_query->row['type'] == 'text' || $option_query->row['type'] == 'textarea' || $option_query->row['type'] == 'file' || $option_query->row['type'] == 'date' || $option_query->row['type'] == 'datetime' || $option_query->row['type'] == 'time') {
```

Remove the check for textarea.

Then after that `elseif`, add another:

```
elseif ($option_query->row['type'] == 'textarea') {

    $word_count = $this->countWords($option_value);
```

*(`countWords()` is a private function you have to add in this cart.php file but you seem to have a handle on that already as you have it in your javascript)*

```
    $product_price = $word_count * $product_query->row['price'];

$option_data[] = array(
    'product_option_id'       => $product_option_id,
    'product_option_value_id' => '',
    'option_id'               => $option_query->row['option_id'],
    'option_value_id'         => '',
    'name'                    => $option_query->row['name'],
    'option_value'            => $option_value,
    'type'                    => $option_query->row['type'],
    'quantity'                => '',
    'subtract'                => '',
    'price'                   => '',
    'price_prefix'            => '',
    'points'                  => '',
    'points_prefix'           => '',                                
    'weight'                  => '',
    'weight_prefix'           => ''
);
}
```

Then below that entire loop where you see

```
$price = $product_query->row['price'];
```

Replace with:

```
if (isset($product_price)) 
    $price = $product_price;
else
    $price = $product_query->row['price'];
```

Obviously the code needs cleaning up and I haven't tested it at all (e.g. it will trigger for all textarea options), but that's how I'd approach it. Though I'm not sure if it's much help if as you say your PHP knowledge is minimal.

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply.
So ive got the product part done, but im stuck on the cart.php

This is the chunk that i've ended up with, http://pastebin.com/aQzAw4QL, after pressing "Add to cart" everything becomes white

Pretty sure it has to do with the"countwords" part, that i didnt really get

Comment: Countwords is just a php function that counts the number of words in the text. Does the same thing as that JavaScript function you already have.  I just meant you'll have to come up with this yourself.

Comment: oh i see, im going to try to do that then, could i ask for assistance please, where shall this function be within the file, and from what part of the file is it counting words?

Comment: It'll just be a function like any of the others within the Cart class in this file (`system/library/cart.php`) - Adding it at the bottom would do the trick.  It counts the words supplied to it in the call `$this->countWords($option_value);` as described in my original reply. And `$option_value` would contain the value typed into the textarea.